# Adding students to a virtual classroom

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my web app, there are 2 kinds of users: **Teachers** and **Students**

> **The Teachers:**
>   - can create classrooms with unique classroom ID
>   - can view his/her students in each classroom he/she created
>
> **The Students**
>   - can join a classroom/s created by a Teacher using classroom IDs
>   - can view classmates from each he/she joined

For the **Teacher** I used these codes to create classrooms :

```
function classcreation(q)
{
    var usuid = generateId();
    var myClasses={};
    myClasses.TheClass = document.getElementById('classroomName').value;
    myClasses.Teacher = user.displayName;
    myClasses.TeacherID = user.uid;
    myClasses.ClassID = usuid;
    fbclass.child(user.uid).push().set(myClasses);
}
```

And these codes to view each user.teachers created classrooms:

```
var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + user.uid);
userRef.on('child_added', function(data)
{
    var roomNames = data.val().TheClass;
    var Studentx = data.val().TheStudents;
    var classD = data.val().ClassID;
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(ul);
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);

    Object.keys(roomNames).forEach(function(key)
    {
        li.innerHTML += '<span 
            onclick="clickDone(this)">'+roomNames[key]+'</span> 
            <ul style="display:none"><li>Class Id : 
            '+classD+'</li><li>Students : '+Studentx+'</li> 
            </ul>';
    });
});
```

I attempted to use these codes for user.students to join a classroom

```
function addclass() {
    var addclassID = document.getElementById("classroomID").value;
    var checkclassID = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes' + '/' + 
    user.uid);

    userRef.on('child_added', function(data)
    {
        var studentx = data.val().TheStudents;
        var clazzID = data.val().ClassID;
        Object.keys(clazzID).forEach(function(key)
        {
            if(clazzID[key] == addclassID) {
                var myClass{};
                myClass.Studentname= user.displayName;
                checkclassID.child("MyStudents").set(myClass);
            } 
            else
            {
                alert("Class doesnt exist!");
            }
        });
    }}
```

I believe the codes below is incorrect:

```
Object.keys(clazzID).forEach(function(key)
{
    if(clazzID[key] == addclassID) {
        var myClass{};
        myClass.Studentname= user.displayName;
        checkclassID.child("MyStudents").set(myClass);
    }
```

What did I miss? What should be the alternative way/codes for students to join a particular class?

Class Image

[image]

So, under the **Classes** is the user.uid, under the user.uid is a random id sent by the push(), below it are the information of a classroom such as ClassID, Teacher, TeacherID, and TheClass which is the classname. If a user.student successfully joined a classroom,a MyStudents should appear on the same level of the information: => ClassID,Teacher,TeacherID,TheClass, MyStudent. Under the MyStudents, it is where the data of the user.student should be place after he/she joined a classroom.

For more clarifications just comment it down below. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

**JSON:**

```
{
  "Accounts" : {
    "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1" : {
      "displayName" : "Dodong Advices",
      "email" : "advicenidodong@gmail.com",
      "status" : "Teacher"
    },
  }
  "Classes" : {
    "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1" : {
      "-LMpvlBl3mEazhxaJwqb" : {
        "ClassID" : "6503-3503-6827",
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "StackMates"
      },
      "-LMrfIBg8v-hj1k8X2Qf" : {
        "ClassID" : "7583-2402-2757",
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "asdasd"
      },
      "-LMrfMV1aw3YNA0PfooR" : {
        "ClassID" : "8083-2712-3347",
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "HAHAHAHA"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JSON that I'm trying to accomplish:** ps: I added a new student user

```
{
  "Accounts" : {
    "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1" : {
      "displayName" : "Dodong Advices",
      "email" : "advicenidodong@gmail.com",
      "status" : "Teacher"
    },
    "HOgdSlTed9V8g0kSZjizgODMDOe2" : {
      "displayName" : "Sasuke Uchiha",
      "email" : "Sasuke@gmail.com",
      "status" : "Student"
    },
    "yJif4ReTxCcGmo682xWSG3L5MKE3" : {
      "displayName" : "Naruto Uzumaki",
      "email" : "Naruto@gmail.com",
      "status" : "Student"
    },
    "yo9hQLNUtOhSVn9xEhBT7uDI72y1" : {
      "displayName" : "Itachi Uchiha",
      "email" : "Itachi@gmail.com",
      "status" : "Teacher"
    }
  },
  "Classes" : {
    "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1" : {
      "-LMpvlBl3mEazhxaJwqb" : {
        "ClassID" : "6503-3503-6827",
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "StackMates"
      },
      "-LMrfIBg8v-hj1k8X2Qf" : {
        "ClassID" : "7583-2402-2757",
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "OverFlowers"
      },
      "-LMrfMV1aw3YNA0PfooR" : {
        "ClassID" : "8083-2712-3347",
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "CodeHard"
      }
    },
    "yo9hQLNUtOhSVn9xEhBT7uDI72y1" : {
      "-LMw39kVqsi5sYbudFSk" : {
        "ClassID" : "3514-2160-0317",
        "Teacher" : "Itachi Uchiha",
        "TeacherID" : "yo9hQLNUtOhSVn9xEhBT7uDI72y1",
        "TheClass" : "Akatsuki",
        "MyStudents" : {
           "HOgdSlTed9V8g0kSZjizgODMDOe2" : {
              "StudentName" : "Sasuke Uchiha"
           }
        }
      },
      "-LMw3A_hP2vkKyaowt8J" : {
        "ClassID" : "7647-8387-3883",
        "Teacher" : "Itachi Uchiha",
        "TeacherID" : "yo9hQLNUtOhSVn9xEhBT7uDI72y1",
        "TheClass" : "Konoha",
        "MyStudents" : {
          "HOgdSlTed9V8g0kSZjizgODMDOe2" : {
              "StudentName" : "Sasuke Uchiha",
          "yJif4ReTxCcGmo682xWSG3L5MKE3" : {
              "StudentName" : "Naruto Uzumaki"
           }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Result of Mr. Frank's Code

```
{
  "Accounts" : {
    "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1" : {
      "displayName" : "Dodong Advices",
      "email" : "advicenidodong@gmail.com",
      "status" : "Teacher"
    },
    "HOgdSlTed9V8g0kSZjizgODMDOe2" : {
      "displayName" : "Sweet Macaroni",
      "email" : "Sweetm@gmail.com",
      "status" : "Student"
    }
  },
  "Classes" : {
    "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1" : {
      "-LMpvlBl3mEazhxaJwqb" : {
        "ClassID" : "6503-3503-6827",
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "StackMates"
      },
      "-LMrfIBg8v-hj1k8X2Qf" : {
        "ClassID" : "7583-2402-2757",
        "Teacher" : "Dodong Advices",
        "TeacherID" : "FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1",
        "TheClass" : "GoogleHub"
      },
      "7583-2402-2757" : {
        "MyStudents" : {
          "HOgdSlTed9V8g0kSZjizgODMDOe2" : {
            "Studentname" : "Sweet Macaroni"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Then show in the JSON what you're trying to accomplish with `addclass`, because right now I'm having hard time parsing your description into code.

Comment: I've updated the question mr. frank, you can now see the json

Comment: Thanks for that. Now please also show the JSON that you're trying to accomplish in `addclass`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me sir! You can now view it. Sorry for the delay

Comment: Just let me know if u can help me or not sir, I'll be waiting :(

Comment: Thanks again for the update. This requires that you know two UIDs in your `addclass` function: the UID of the teacher, and the UID of the student. Do you know both?

Comment: Yes sir, it is in my Firebase Database

Comment: And also a teacher can ask what is the uid of his/her students and also vice versa, if that's what you mean sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you must know two UIDs: the one for the student, and the one for the teacher. With those, the code can be quite simple:

```
function addclass() {
    var addclassID = document.getElementById("classroomID").value;
    var teacherUID = ...; // ?
    var studentUID = user.uid;
    var studentName = user.displayName;
    var classRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes').child(teacherUID).child(addclassID);
    var studentsRef = classRef.child("MyStudents");
    studentsRef.child(studentUID).set({ Studentname: studentName });
}
```

#### Update

As commented: since your classes already have their own unique ID, I *highly* recommend using that as the key when you store them. That's what the code above does.

In your current structure you'll first have to query to find the key of the class, and then write it there. Your code was doing that by loading all classes and then looping, but it's easier if you query:

```
function addclass() {
    var addclassID = document.getElementById("classroomID").value;
    var teacherUID = ...; // ?
    var studentUID = user.uid;
    var studentName = user.displayName;
    var classRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes').child(teacherUID);
    classRef.orderByChild("ClassID").equalTo(addclassID).once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      var studentsRef = snapshot.ref.child("MyStudents");
      studentsRef.child(studentUID).set({ Studentname: studentName });
    });
}
```

Comment: So, i should make another input in my html to ask for the teacher uid and then store it in a var? For example var teacherUID = document.getElementByID("teacherID").value;

Comment: Btw, what is .set(myClass); for sir?

Comment: You can use it to set an existing JSON object. My code just has the same structure inlined in the `set()` call.

Comment: So, I need to add var myClass{}; ? and then what sir? myClass.addclassID? Sorry im a little bit confused

Comment: Sorry for being such an idiot sir. But, where does that .set(myClass); come from?

Comment: Oops... sorry about that. That was a leftover from copy/pasting your code. I removed it now.

Comment: The code actually worked sir, but instead of the myStudents being inserted on the same level of TheClass, it actually created another child. I updated the question so that you will understand what I mean sir. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Note sure I understand. As far as I can see in your latest JSON: `FykyhzEZjndylFj3BbCnPqoTGDo1` is the teacher's UID, `7583-2402-2757` is the class ID, and `HOgdSlTed9V8g0kSZjizgODMDOe2` is the student ID. Did you want the code to look up the key for class `7583-2402-2757`? If the class ID is already unique, I'd recommend using that as the key instead.

Comment: can you help me one last time? :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this -

```
function addclass() {
    var addclassID = document.getElementById("classroomID").value;
    var teacherUID = ...; // ?
    var studentUID = user.uid;
    var studentName = user.displayName;
    var classRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Classes').child(teacherUID);
    classRef.child(addclassID);
    var studentsRef = classRef.child("MyStudents");
    studentsRef.child(studentUID).set({ Studentname: studentName });
}
```

Comment: It worked sir but how do you make the MyStudents belong to the same level as the ClassID,Teacher,TeacherID,TheClass?

Comment: send it to your gmail or here?

Comment: [github link](https://github.com/RonchiTech/TheRead/tree/canJoinClass(2))

Comment: Sir I have some questions